# My computer boots to a black screen with blinking cursor on the top left

Tags: boot, nvidia, startup

I'm sorry for my poor English. My computer suddenly came to this problem after I unplugged and plugged the graphic card. Before this everything was fine. All I do was unplugging the card and plugging it back again (computer power off).

It can boot to the grub. However, after choosing system, it showed the following message then switched to black screen with cursor blinking.

```
/dev/sdb6:clean, 2273922/74129408 files, 220451532/296508672 blocks
```

My computer has double systems of Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7.
it cannot boot to Win7 either except the safe mode.

I have already tried and checked the following things, which didn't help:

- Disable nouveau and re-install NVIDIA driver through recovery mode.
- Editting the commands in GRUB: changing `quiet splash` to `no splash` or `nomodeset`.
- using `df -h` to check if the hard drive is full. It's only 80% used.

Then I changed the `quiet splash` to `text`, and the messages are as follows. During this the screen went black and got back on several times. And I think the resolution changed a little. Then the screen went black with cursor blinking eventually.

[image]

[image]

The FAILED item is:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Clean up any mess left by Odns-up
```

Any suggestions about what this problem might be? Thank you!

---

Update:
The computer can boot somehow.
I've tried to clean the dust on the motherboard and the graphic card slot. I also plugged other graphic cards to test. At first it didn't help. But after rebooting several times the computer suddenly booted somehow. I have no idea what changed.

Comment: Hi and welcome. The message you have seen is a hard drive problem. It is trying to fix the file system. The fact you also get this error on the other OS as well just reinforces this fact. Nothing with the graphic card or changing boot settings will fix this.  Also 16.04 is out of standard support in a few weeks time to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04.

Comment: Yeah I'm also considering updating the system.  I think this might be caused by the hardware problem, too. Anyway thank you for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen quite often after a hardware change with quick boot enabled. This skips the hardware check.

Try to disable quick boot in bios, then restart. After successful boot, you can enable quick boot again.

Comment: Thank you! I've checked the BIOS setting but there is no 'quick boot' or 'fast boot'. Do you know any other settings that might related?

Comment: Google your laptop model and enable fast boot. Maybe it is named "skip hardware check" or something like this.